# Adding value to row in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

So I am using impala trying to write a sql statement that does the follows：

```
 col1  col2
 1     Null
```

Insert/Update a value into col2 where the value is calculated by a select Max(price).
So the expected output will be

```
 col1  col2
 1     price
```

I am trying with the update function, but it seems that impala does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*, max(price) over () as new_price
from t;
```

Comment: What will this return?

Comment: @JamesXiang . . . An additional column with the maximum price.